# SSRS Conditional Border Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have report as `table` component. I want to apply the following logic:

If value `INCID` is not null, the border should be "`Solid`" (meaning it should have border),
If value `INCID` is null, the border should be "`None`" (meaning the table should have no border).

I used `=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!INCID.Value) = 1,"Solid","None")` but it doesn't work. Where could be the problem? If I apply this and save this settings and then go back to the expression, it is not saved.

Comment: try it in this way =IIf(IsNothing(Fields!INCID.Value),"None","Solid")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, **[this](http://www.joellipman.com/articles/microsoft/sql-server/ssrs/479-border-settings-not-saving-in-ssrs.html)** seemed to be the problem.

Answer (score 5):

3 Years late, but my answer was different and maybe will help someone else one day.

I was able to make the expression work by entering it into the BorderStyle Properties.

Click on a given cell > Open Properties > Expand BorderStyle > Choose desired Side of Cell > Enter iif expression.

For example the following worked for me:

```
=iif(MAX(Fields!DistinctDevicecount.Value) > 1, "Solid", "None")
```

Comment: This should definitely be marked the answer.  The other suggested solution works,  but the real solution is to enter the expressions into the report properties.

Comment: This didn't work for me. This is the only way I have set borders in my reports. It worked until our reports were being exported to XLS format. Stopped working as soon as we switched to XLSX.

Comment: @SudarshanKadam Yep I see the same issue as well. If the intention is to hide the borders similar to my original example, you could instead change the border color (using the BoderColor property rather than BorderStyle) to white. I have confirmed this works when exported to .xlsx

Comment: @MPJ567 So we raised this to MS and I think they are going to release a CU soon that fixes it. No idea when 'soon' is though. If you still have this issue, keep an eye on the SQL 2016 Cumulative Updates.

Comment: Here it is https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4527378/cumulative-update-11-for-sql-server-2016-sp2

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in Sql 2016 CU https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4527378/cumulative-update-11-for-sql-server-2016-sp2